# Finding largest contiguous sub-array sum with distinct numbers

Tags: algorithm, arrays

In given array find largest contiguous sub-array sum with distinct numbers. If in any sub-array there are at least two equal numbers, than values of that numbers are equal to 0.

All numbers are positive.

I wrote O(n²) brute-force algorithm, but it's definitely too slow.
I tried to mix it using Kadane's algorithm, but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: have u tried sorting the array and inserting all distinct numbers ? O(n*log(n)) for sorting + O(n) for insertion

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies it is not correct. For an array 5, 2, 2, 4 it is optimal to pick the entire array, even though not all numbers are distinct.

Comment: I guess I didnt understand the question. If the subArray is 5,2,2,4, its sum is (5+4=9) instead of taking (5,4,2) which sums up to 11, so why take the whole array?

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies Subarray is a consecutive thing. It is not possible to take 5, 4, 2 because they are not consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to obtain `O(n log n)` time complexity using segment tree.

1. Let's assume that the left border(let's call it `L`) of the answer is fixed. Everything to the left from it can be ignored. Each element of the rest of the array can be represented as either:
   a)`+x` if it is the first occurrence of `x`.
   b)`-x` if it is the second occurrence of `x`.
   c)`0` if it is the third(or later) occurrence of `x`,
   where `x = a[i]`.
   Then the answer is the largest subarray sum for all subarrays `[L, R]` where `R >= L`.
2. So how can it be implemented efficiently? Initially, build a segment tree for `[0, n - 1]` range. Each leaf in the segment tree contains prefix sum that starts in `L` and ends in this leaf(`0` so far). Fill it for `L = 0`(by iterating over the entire array and adding `+x` or `-x` to appropriate suffices in segment tree). These part works in `O(n log n)`. One more observation: when `L` is incremented, the value changes only for at most 3 positions(because the first occurrence for a number `a[L]` is now in another position, but for the other numbers nothing has changed). Each update in the segment tree is `O(log n)`, thus `O(log n)` time is required for incrementing `L` once. The total time complexity is `O(n log n)`, because `L` is incremented `O(n)` times. Do not forget to query the segment tree to get maximum value for every `L` and choose the largest one as the answer.

So all what you need is a segment tree that supports two operations: add the same number to all elements in a given range and get maximum among all elements. It is a well-known problem and is not really hard to implement.

Comment: Well, I guess you're right! But I still don't understand what should I do when incrementing L, could you explain me? Thank you!

Comment: Let's look at the number a[L]. Its first and second positions sfiht to the right when L is incremented. So +a[L] and -a[L] are located in other positions now and the segment tree should updated appropriatly(if you store all positions for a given number, you can find new positions quickly using binary search or by moving a pointer when you move L).